# AngularJS make elements tabbable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have something that looks like this:

```
'<div class="ui360-infoSectionHeader">' +
    '<span ng-click="toggle()" class="ui360-infoSectionTitle" ng-class="{\'ui360-expanded\':isExpanded, \'ui360-collapsed\':!isExpanded}">{{sectionTitle}}</span>' +
'</div>'
```

How can I make it so when I tab through the page, the span receives focus and I can trigger the ng-click using ENTER? I was able to do it by changing the span to an 'a' tag and adding an `href="#"` but that was refreshing the page which is not at all what I need. I also want to avoid using the tab index because this is a directive that could be placed anywhere on the page. I would just like it to get focus when it's supposed to in relation to the other elements on the page. How is this done?

Comment: use tabindex and create a directive for the keypress handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use the anchor tag but instead of using `href="#"` use `href="javascript:return false"`